# d3.js text events registered but not triggering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I have the following enter section which is transitioned later to set the opacity to 1. The 'click' on the circle works. The 'click' on the text does not.

If I substitute the 'text' for a 'rect' and set the appropriate attributes on the rect then both clicks function correctly.

When I inspect the dom tree, the listeners are correctly visible on both the circle and the text elements.

Could somebody possibly point out any obvious mistakes or tell me why using 'text' won't work with a listener?

```
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('transform', function () {
      return 'translate(' + source.y0 + ',' + source.x0 + ')';
     })
    .style('opacity', 1e-6);

  nodeEnter.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6)
    .style('fill', function (d: any) {
    return d._children ? 'lightsteelblue' : '#fff';
  })
  .on('click', this.circle_click);

  nodeEnter.append('text')
    .attr('dx', 3.5)
    .attr('dy', 5.5)
    .text(function (d: any) { return d.data.name; })
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
    .on('click', this.text_click);
```

Comment: Impossible to answer this question if we don't know what is `text_click` and `circle_click`.

Comment: You're right - but in this case they are currently just printing messages to the console.

Answer (score -2):

Discovered that for some reason 'pointer-events "none"' was always set on the element - when I specifically set the style to "visible" during the update transition then it worked. Would be interesting to know why this happened - the style certainly wasn't set in either my code or css files.